# Оптимизация кода / алгоритма

Tags: python, алгоритм, оптимизация

Есть такая задача:
Найти пары станций, для которых выгоднее будет сделать одну пересадку, чем поехать напрямую.
Удалось "придумать" такой код:

```
n = int(input())
data = [[]] + [list(map(int, input().split())) for i in range(n)]
res = []
for j in range(n):
    for i in range(j+1, n):
        direct = data[i][j]
        for k in range(n):
            if k==i or k==j:
                continue
            inter = (data[k][j] if k > j else data[j][k]) + \
                    (data[k][i] if k > i else data[i][k])
            if direct > inter:
                res.append((j, i))
print(res)
```

Однако мне хотелось бы узнать о более удачных *по времени* способах решения (использование другого алгоритма или оптимизация этого)

---

Входные данные: число станций `n`, `n-1` строк стоимостей от станции `n` к станции `k`, `k<n`
Фактически, нам дают нижнию часть матрицы стоимостей.
Пара примеров
Вход:

```
3
57 
14 39
```

Выход:

```
[(0, 1)]
```

Вход:

```
4
23 
87 71 
100 1 95
```

Выход

```
[(0, 3), (2, 3)]
```

---

Нашел способ ускорения:

```
n = int(input())
data = [[]] + [list(map(int, input().split())) for i in range(n)]
res = set() # <---
for j in range(n):
    for i in range(j+1, n):
        direct = data[i][j]
        for k in range(n):
            if k==i or k==j:
                continue
            if k>i:
                inter = data[k][i] + data[k][j]
            elif k>j:
                inter = data[i][k] + data[k][j]
            else:
                inter = data[i][k]+ data[j][k]
            if direct > inter:
                res.add((j, i)) # <---
                break # <---
print(res)
```

Comment: Можно использовать алгоритм Дейкстры https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC_%D0%94%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%8B с небольшими модификациями ввиду ограниченности количества допустимых пересадок

Comment: по-моему во втором примере данных правильным ответом будет: `[(0, 1), (1, 3)]`

Comment: @MaxU практическая (модули можно). путь (3, 1) равен единице. нет ничего выгоднее

Comment: За `N^3` тривиальное решение не годится?

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy и у меня и так вроде как почти тривиальное. да и сложность та же. но посмотреть не откажусь :)

Comment: У вас нормальное решение. Если не надо быстрее (я пока не знаю можно ли вообще быстрее) то всё ОК.

Comment: @n1tr0xs, я сначала неправильно понял формат вывода. Смотрите "Shortest path algorithms for weighed graphs." [здесь](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/shortest_paths.html)

Comment: А нельзя ли чуть чуть подправить вопрос, чтобы там в самом вопросе было определение "что такое выгоднее"?

Comment: @S.H. быстрее. подправил.